# Repeated column in mapping for entity in @OneToOne

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, one-to-one

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
    id              INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    username        VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
    password        VARCHAR(68) NOT NULL,
    oldPassword     VARCHAR(68),
    enabled BOOLEAN NOT NULL
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE authorities (
                             id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                             username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                             authority VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
                             FOREIGN KEY (username) REFERENCES users(username)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_auth_username on authorities (username,authority);
```

Unfortunatelly instead of joining with `authority_id` which should be in `users` table I just have `username` which is the same in both tables.

In models I tried (ommited getters and setters):

```
@Entity(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String oldPassword;
    private boolean enabled;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "username", referencedColumnName = "username")
    private Authorities authority;
}
```

and

```
@Entity
public class Authorities {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String authority;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "authority")
    private User user;
}
```

but then I have an error: `Repeated column in mapping for entity column: username (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")`

Answer (score 0):

The message is clear: you have a repeated column in the mapping, and a column "username" in both tables has repeated. Instead of this, you should use this :

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "authority_username", referencedColumnName = "username")
private Authorities authority;
```

Comment: thanks for answer however it didn't help a lot - when I just do `userRepository.findAll();` it throws an error:
`org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Column "USER0_.AUTHORITY_USERNAME" not found; SQL statement:
select user0_.id as id1_3_, user0_.authority_username as authorit6_3_, user0_.enabled as enabled2_3_, user0_.oldPassword as oldpassw3_3_, user0_.password as password4_3_, user0_.username as username5_3_ from users user0_ [42122-214]`

Comment: Of course, my solution is to solve the Repeated column problem, if you want the "username" column as the foreign key of  User tables,  this column must be primary-key of the Authorities tables and vice versa

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting usernames in both tables is that you have declared username column in both the tables.

Also, you have to map the relation based on the authority_id so the code of the models would look like this:

```
@Entity(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String oldPassword;
    private boolean enabled;
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "authority_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Authorities authority;
}


@Entity
public class Authorities {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private String authority;
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "authority")
    private User user;
}
```

And the tables will be created like this:

[image]

[image]

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Yes, with adding `authority_id` it's okay but can I somehow achive the same with just `username` as foreign key?